# how to match IP addresses with ASN data (maxmind)?

Tags: ip-address, maxmind

I am looking at the data here https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2-asn-csv-database/

that contains, as explained:

1. The IPv4 or IPv6 network in CIDR format such as “2.21.92.0/29” or “2001:4b0::/80”. We offer a utility to convert this column to start/end IPs or start/end integers. See the conversion utility section for details.
2. The autonomous system number associated with the IP address.
3. The organization associated with the registered autonomous system number for the IP address.

My question is: from a regular IPv4 address, how can I match with this data? Can I just match on all the numbers before the `/` (such as `1.0.0.0/24`
) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should find the beginning and ending IP address of one IP CIDR range and then find it whether if the IP address number is matching in the range.

Comment: thanks! is there a way to genereate the complete dataframe of ip address in R/Python? otherwise it will be very hard to match anything..

Comment: Also, sorry for my noobiness, but is the `ASN organisation` name shown in the data the same thing as the `domain name` in the commercial maxmind datasets?

Comment: No, domain name is "abc.com" and ASN organization could be "ABC Inc." if they owned the AS.